# Why ngTemplateOutlet is not working when I pass a variable/object?

Tags: javascript, angular, ng-template

```
    <form *ngIf="filters">
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="filterTemplate; context: {$implicit: filters}"></ng-container>
    </form>

    <ng-template #filterTemplate let-filters>
      <ng-container *ngFor="let field of filters">
        {field.something}
      </ng-container>
    <ng-template>
```

`filters` in ng-container is null, can anyone tell me where/what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have *ngTemplateOutlet="filterFileds; but ng-template #filterTemplate, why ?

Comment: My bad, fixed it

Comment: It is the same, I've just wrote differently by mistake here

Comment: `<ng-container let field of filters>` not sure what you are trying to do here

Comment: @Morphyish still my bad, can you check it again, please

Comment: Seems ok to me, problem must be somewhere else. Can you add a repro?

Comment: `{field.something}` this is also wrong , it should be `{{field.something}}` @Donovant

Comment: @VivekDoshi oh my gosh still my bad (just here), sorry :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If you are setting up `filters` data proper** then there is **no issue** in your code :

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="filterTemplate; context: {$implicit: filters}"></ng-container>

<ng-template #filterTemplate let-filters>
  <ng-container *ngFor='let field of filters'>
    {{field.key}}<br/>
  </ng-container>
<ng-template>
```

**[WORKING DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tempalteref-loop)** ( With ngIf / and simulated data delay with setTimeout)